# If I know the address (hex value of a function) then can I assing it to function pointer/or some variable with same signature if yes then how

Tags: c, linux

I have a function like this

```
void abc()
 {
   printf("hello\n");
 }
```

lets suppose I checked and know that the address of above function say `0x08000040` now if I assign it to function pointer in main like this

```
 int main()
    {
          void (*p)()=(void *)0x08000040;
          
          p();// and call it like 
          return 0;
    }
```

will it call some how. I tried it does not work but suppose I have function in the same program then will it work after I some how found out the address of the function?

and also is this possible

1. to assign specific fixed address to some function in current C program
2. is it possible to export a function address (of `abc()`) in current program and so other programs can call the function in this program to call above `abc()` function with address hex values. it happens in kernel with exporting of sys-calls and gdb also does this with trap-handlers. So is there any easy way to make it work.

[image: this is how I found the address with radare2]

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Compilation error? Segfault? BTW: Why do you cast to `void*` if your target is `void(*)()`?

Comment: @Gerhardh SegFault

Comment: even removing `cast to void*` still segFault

Comment: Basically this mechanism can work. Shared libraries have to deal with similar problems. Nevertheless the memory area that you want to call as a function must be executable for your process. Some memory managament unit might object to your idea of calling memory not inside your program area.

Comment: Where does that `0x08000040`  address come from? Does this run under Linux? I think you should tell us more.

Comment: @Gerhardh yes that brings me to other question if I want to export `abc()` then does this only possible with shared library or any executable program function can be exported

Comment: Most systems nowadays use memory randomization, so you will never know the address in advance.

Comment: @Jabberwocky its from other program

Comment: @user786 please tell us more. How _exactly_ do you get this address. _"its from other program"_ sounds fishy.

Comment: @user786 That propably won't work, because libraries usually get different virtual addresses per process.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I used radare2 to find the address

Comment: @user786 please [edit] the question and add some more context information about what you are _actually_ trying to achieve and what you are _actually_ doing.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have edited the question with tool I used the commands for it I used

Comment: The function you show destroys `rdi` which is a callee save register, so it can not be directly called from `c`. Not sure if there is a calling convention which allows this. Depends on your ABI.

Comment: @Devolus  rdi register: `Architectures define a calling convention which dictates where parameters to a function and its return value are stored.` how did u find out function distroys rdi. what does this mean?

Comment: It shows on the screenshot you posted `lea rdi,[address]`. This register must be saved, so you need a wrapper that does that, because the above function does not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: @Devolus and `need a wrapper` means? please clarify with simple code in comment. thanks for help

Comment: I can only post some pseudocode to show you how it should work, so you would have to implement the final solution on your own.

Comment: ok thanks please do so

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void abc(void) {
    puts("abc");
}

void cba(void) {
    puts("cba");
}

int main(void) {
    printf("type %p or %p\n", (void*)abc, (void*)cba);
    char buf[100];
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
    long unsigned u = strtoul(buf + 2, NULL, 16);   // ignore 0x
    void (*p)(void) = (void(*)(void))u;             // UB!
    p(); // and call it
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about if the function is in different program

Comment: Ah, then the OS doesn't allow it. Granting your program read access to random memory in the system is a big security risk that modern OSes try to prevent, ***I think***.

Comment: This solution only works because all functions are following the same/known calling conventions. For an arbitrary pointer, like in your screenshot, this is not the case.

Comment: Simplification: `strtoul(buf + 2, NULL, 16);` -> `strtoul(buf, NULL, 0);`

Comment: Alternative: `strtoul(buf + 2, NULL, 16);` -> `strtoul(buf, NULL, 16);` because `strtoul()` ignores the `0x` or `0X` prefix for base 16 conversion. If the base argument is `0`, the presence of this prefix will force base 16 conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual address where a given function is located in memory is entirely implementation defined and further depends on many factors:

- it is almost always different for different programs ;
- it may change if you modify the program source code and recompile it ;
- it may even change each time you execute the same program: modern systems perform address space randomisation in order to reduce vulnerability to certain classes of attacks. The same applies to the stack address.

Do not rely on the address values you observe in the debugger, they are likely to be different the next time you debug the program.